# Multiple CF7 Forms causing multiple recaptcha requests

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

On some sites we add multiple CF7 forms for different enquires / services - the issues i've found though is that having multiple instances is causing multiple requests for the same reCaptcha.

The multiple files are causing an extra 100 requests in some cases.

Any ideas how to get around it other than combining forms of updating to CF7 v5.1 (recaptcha v3)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall, from reading on the CF7 support forum (which is where this question really needs to be instead of here), that the latest CF7 (which uses recaptcha v3) adds the recaptcha code to all pages on the site, not just the CF7 pages. Even if you don't enable recaptcha v3.

Not too many people happy about that. Which is why I haven't updated CF7 on the sites I run.

I'm converting CF7 forms on my sites to another self-written form process (which defeats spam bots easily - even without using recaptchas).

Free code to do that at https://formspammertrap.com (I'll modify this if that link is not allowed.)